# convert the byteArray to bitmap in android?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, arrays

In my web service images are stored in byteArray format.i want to convert the bitmap image.

i have attached my code here .

```
  BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(AndroidJSONParsingActivity.inputStream);
             Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
             ByteArrayOutputStream companylogo = new
             ByteArrayOutputStream();
             ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
             image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
//if bitmapdata is the byte array then getting bitmap goes like this

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
Returns The decoded bitmap, or null if the image could not be decode.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
// Camera arg conversion to Bitmap
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(Your_byte_array_image, 0,
                            Your_byte_array_image.length);
Bitmap back = Bitmap.createBitmap(background.getWidth(),
                        background.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Use this bitmap.

Comment: i have so many byte array images how to make into image.for ex logo:[137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,128,8,6,0,0,0,195] in json format in my webservice

Comment: This could help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021526/retrieve-byte-in-android-from-json-webservice
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403862/java-parse-json-byte-array